# How to layer two textures in a cylinder without Z-fighting?

Tags: unity

In the documentation of [ShaderLab culling and depth testing](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/SL-CullAndDepth.html) you have the following:

> Offset

> Offset Factor, Units

> Allows you specify a depth offset with two parameters. factor and units. Factor scales the maximum Z slope, with respect to X or Y of the polygon, and units scale the minimum resolvable depth buffer value. This allows you to force one polygon to be drawn on top of another although they are actually in the same position. For example Offset 0, -1 pulls the polygon closer to the camera
> ignoring the polygon’s slope, whereas Offset -1, -1 will pull the polygon even closer when looking at a grazing angle.

I have the following scenery, it's two cylinders of the **same size**, one being the sky, one being the horizon on the floor, it is shown exactly how it is expected to render:

[image]

This is how it actually looks without playing with the offset factor and units, lots of Z-fighting:

[image]

I had to put a fairly high value to `Factor` so Z-fighting stops, around 15.

And setting the value of `Units` has absolutely no effect.

So I'm a bit at a loss as on how to correctly use both of these parameters.

**Question:**

Can you explain how shall one understand the meaning and correctly use `Factor` and `Units`?

Comment: I would not use Offset to solve this problem. Can you instead draw the sky before the city, and turn off z writes for the sky so it leaves no obstacles for the city that's drawn second? Or even better, layer both textures in one shader so you can draw it in a single pass with half the fillrate and no blend mode needed when writing to the frame buffer.

Comment: @DMGregory What do you mean exactly by drawing the sky before the city, drawing manually using `Graphics.DrawMesh` or something like that in `PostRender` ? For the second approach I suppose you have optimization in mind ? Going to give this a try.

Comment: [You can control ordering with the queue tag](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/SL-SubShaderTags.html), without getting into script-based solutions.

Comment: Actually this is the first thing I've tried but it didn't work well, read here that sometimes it did, sometimes it didn't, going to try again.

Comment: @DMGregory Tried again, no matter what queue orider I set it doesn't work ... but if I lower polygon count in cylinder it does work ... sometimes. Sticking to offset as it just works.

Comment: If you show us what you've tried (a minimal complete verifiable example) we can help you fix it. But without that there's not much we can do.

Comment: Actually you're right, now I'm starting seeing the problems using offset... I really would like to post an example but there is simply too much code to show, I'll continue digging in the solution you suggested.

Comment: Sounds like you have some work to do to build a Minimal Complete Verifiable Example.

Comment: Thanks to your comments, I realized I could fix it by simply blitting both images in a texture, the problem is now gone.

Comment: Want to share your solution as an answer below? You might also want to change the question to "How to layer two textures in a cylinder without Z-fighting?" if offset/factor/units are not a necessary part of the answer.

Comment: Alright, thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @DMGregory suggested, a shader with two textures turned out to be the best choice.

[image]

[image]

```
// NOTE texture 'alpha is transparency' should be false to disable dilation

Shader "Custom/Two Textures Alpha Blending"
{
    Properties
    {
        _MainTex ("Texture 1", 2D) = "white" {}
        _NextTex ("Texture 2", 2D) = "white" {}
    }
    SubShader
    {
        Tags { "RenderType"="Opaque" }
        LOD 100

        Pass
        {
            CGPROGRAM
            #pragma vertex vert
            #pragma fragment frag

            #include "UnityCG.cginc"

            struct appdata
            {
                float4 vertex : POSITION;
                float2 uv : TEXCOORD0;
            };

            struct v2f
            {
                float2 uv1 : TEXCOORD0;
                float2 uv2 : TEXCOORD1;
                float4 vertex : SV_POSITION;
            };

            sampler2D _MainTex;
            sampler2D _NextTex;
            float4 _MainTex_ST;
            float4 _NextTex_ST;

            v2f vert (appdata v)
            {
                v2f o;
                o.vertex = UnityObjectToClipPos(v.vertex);
                o.uv1 = TRANSFORM_TEX(v.uv, _MainTex);
                o.uv2 = TRANSFORM_TEX(v.uv, _NextTex);
                return o;
            }

            fixed4 frag (v2f i) : SV_Target
            {
                // https://forum.unity.com/threads/what-is-the-formula-for-blending-two-transparent-textures-in-a-shader.169313/
                fixed4 c1 = tex2D(_MainTex, i.uv1);
                fixed4 c2 = tex2D(_NextTex, i.uv2);
                fixed3 c3 = c2.rgb * (1.0 - c1.a) + c1.rgb;
                return float4(c3, 1.0);
            }
            ENDCG
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you consider skipping the blit step, and just sample both textures when rendering your cylinder?

Comment: Well, that means that I'd have to write another shader while I've already my own `uber` shader . The thing is I'm working on a lot of code-generated stuff for more or less a Doom engine for an old video game... But yes, indeed it should be a better idea.

Comment: @DMGregory It turns out that you're right again, making a custom shader with two textures will save me from the hassle of writing some code to blit bitmaps over bitmaps 

Comment: @DMGregory Thanks mate, it works perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

You should use one cylinder, in the pixel shader blend between the two textures. You may also need to generate mip maps for the textures.